# $Hom_A(\Omega_{A/K},A)$ finitely generated without torsion?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modules, finitely-generated

Consider $A$ a domain which is a finitely generated $K$-algebra for $K$ algebraically closed (say generated by $a_1,\dots,a_n$), define $\tau_{A/K}:=\text{Hom}_A(\Omega_{A/K},A)$, I want to show that it's a finitely generated $A$-module without torsion. Do you have ideas on how to show this ?

I maybe wanted to say that $\tau_{A/K}\cong \text{Der}_K(A,A)$ and consider $d_i:A\to A$ which takes $a=P(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ to $\frac{\partial P}{\partial x_i}(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ but I'm struggling to make it work.

Comment: Note that $A$ is Noetherian, so it’s enough to show that $\tau_{A/K}$ $A$-injects into a finite type $A$-module. Consider $D \in \mathrm{Der}_K(A,A) \longmapsto (D(a_i))_{1 \leq i \leq n}$.

Comment: The map $\text{Der}_K(A,A)$ that you suggest we get that $\text{Der}_K(A,A)$ is isomorphic to a submodule of $A^n$ is this correct ? In particular since $A^n$ is Noetherian $\text{Der}_K(A,A)$ is finitely generated. But $A^n$ is a free $A$-module so $\text{Der}_K(A,A)$ is free (submodules of free modules are free). But the next question I'm asked is to show that if $A$ is regular, $\tau_{A/K}$ is free. Is it incorrect to deduce from what you said that $\text{Der}_K(A,A)$ is free ?

Comment: Careful – submodules of free modules over non-PIDs need not be free (just take a non-principal ideal!).

Comment: I’m really surprised that the sole assumption of $A$ being a regular domain is enough to get global freeness… are you sure it’s the case, or perhaps would $\tau_{A/K}$ be only locally free?

Comment: Does it change your thoughts of $K$ is a algebraically closed ? I'll edit it now since I forgot to say it, but no it's said free if $A$ is regular.

Comment: $A$ is regular of finite type over the algebraically closed field $K$, so $A$ is smooth over $K$ and thus $\Omega^1_{A/K}$ is locally free.